# PHP recursive tree view generator is only selecting one option off a populated "selected" array?

Tags: php, recursion

I have a mostly working recursive tree view generator. Given a parent-child array, it can output it correctly as a string of checkboxes which then get styled by CSS.

It takes two values. The tree array, and a selected array. When it reads a selected value, it appends "checked", but appends an otherwise normal checkbox string when it does not.

However, as soon as it appends a checkbox that is not selected, it can only display the last selected value and seems to completely forget about the remainder of the array.

```
public function genTree($tree, $selectedValues = [1,2,3,4])
{
    $output = '<ul class="treeview">';

    foreach($tree as $arr)
    {
        $output .= '<li>';

        foreach($selectedValues as $num)
        {
            if ($num == $arr['id'])
            {
                $output .= '<input checked type="checkbox" id="'.$arr['name'].'" name="selected[]" value="'.$arr['id'].'"></input>';
            } else {
                $output .= '<input type="checkbox" id="'.$arr['name'].'" name="selected[]" value="'.$arr['id'].'"></input>';    
            }
        }

        $output .= '<label for"'.$arr['name'].'">'.ucfirst($arr['name']).'</label>';    

        if (isset($arr['children']) && count($arr['children']) > 0)
        {       
            $output .= $this->genTree($arr['children'], $selectedValues);   
        }
        $output .= '</li>';
    }
    $output .= '</ul>';

    return $output;
}
```

Line 15 appears to be the problem, but other then that I have no clue what may be happening. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: An example array and/or the resulting output from the function call would be helpful. Your second `foreach` looks odd to me though - are you sure you don't want something like `if (in_array(...))`?

Comment: That actually did the trick. In_array, that is. I was thinking in terms of loops while building the function. Could you write this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second `foreach` looks odd to me - are you sure you don't want something like `if (in_array(...))` instead of an `if` within a `foreach`?

Your `<label>` is missing an `=` on the `for` attribute, too.

Otherwise though, your recursion logic and variable passing looks good.

Comment: Thank you, I got stuck on doing things as loops and hadn't considered in_array.